# How can I use filter in ng-model AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, pug

I want to filter my `DepartmentTmp` variable (content at the end) by departement in ng-model with a code similar as this one : (Department choosen = choices)

```
sk-input-select(ng-model='vm.DepartmentTmp.filters.#DEPARTMENT CHOSEN#', choices='refs.departmentList', ng-change='refs.search()', placeholder='Sélectionner...', allow-clear='true')
```

Here is the DepartmentList :

```
[{"id":1,"label":"Direction","code":"DIR"},
{"id":6,"label":"Pôle commercial","code":"COM"},
{"id":5,"label":"Pôle communication/marketing","code":"MAR"},{"id":3,"label":"Pôle ingénierie logicielle","code":"ING"},
{"id":4,"label":"Pôle web","code":"WEB"},
{"id":2,"label":"Service des ressources humaines","code":"RH"}]
```

Here is what looks like `DepartmentTmp`. As you can see there is an attribute named "departement" with inside the informations about the department.

```
[{"id":9,"username":"alexandra.bauchart","lastName":"Bauchart","firstName":"Alexandra","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":2,"label":"ROLE_AGENT","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":5,"label":"Pôle communication/marketing","code":"MAR"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Alexandra Bauchart","abregate":"AB"},
    {"id":4,"username":"alexandre.bay","lastName":"Bay","firstName":"Alexandre","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":2,"label":"ROLE_AGENT","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":3,"label":"Pôle ingénierie logicielle","code":"ING"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Alexandre Bay","abregate":"AB"},
    {"id":2,"username":"benjamin.ruef","lastName":"Ruef","firstName":"Benjamin","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":2,"label":"ROLE_AGENT","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":3,"label":"Pôle ingénierie logicielle","code":"ING"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Benjamin Ruef","abregate":"BR"},
    {"id":7,"username":"corentin.dauvier","lastName":"Dauvier","firstName":"Corentin","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":2,"label":"ROLE_AGENT","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":3,"label":"Pôle ingénierie logicielle","code":"ING"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Corentin Dauvier","abregate":"CD"},
    {"id":6,"username":"dorothee.wenehoua","lastName":"Wenehoua","firstName":"Dorothee","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":7,"label":"ROLE_RH","canRegulateCounter":true,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":true}],"department":{"id":2,"label":"Service des ressources humaines","code":"RH"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Dorothee Wenehoua","abregate":"DW"},
    {"id":3,"username":"florian.gourmelen","lastName":"Gourmelen","firstName":"Florian","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":3,"label":"ROLE_RESP","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":3,"label":"Pôle ingénierie logicielle","code":"ING"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Florian Gourmelen","abregate":"FG"},
    {"id":5,"username":"hatem.bellagi","lastName":"Bellagi","firstName":"Hatem","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":6,"label":"ROLE_DIR","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":1,"label":"Direction","code":"DIR"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Hatem Bellagi","abregate":"HB"},
    {"id":8,"username":"richard.ratiman","lastName":"Ratiman","firstName":"Richard","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":3,"label":"ROLE_RESP","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":5,"label":"Pôle communication/marketing","code":"MAR"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Richard Ratiman","abregate":"RR"},    
    {"id":12,"username":"rodolphe.bertolini","lastName":"Bertolini","firstName":"Rodolphe","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":2,"label":"ROLE_AGENT","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":3,"label":"Pôle ingénierie logicielle","code":"ING"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Rodolphe Bertolini","abregate":"RB"},
    {"id":10,"username":"simon.larthe","lastName":"Larthe","firstName":"Simon","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":2,"label":"ROLE_AGENT","canRegulateCounter":false,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":false}],"department":{"id":5,"label":"Pôle communication/marketing","code":"MAR"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Simon Larthe","abregate":"SL"},
    {"id":11,"username":"sonia.touahri","lastName":"Touahri","firstName":"Sonia","phone":"","isDeleted":false,"roles":[{"id":7,"label":"ROLE_RH","canRegulateCounter":true,"canSeeRequestAttachFile":true}],"department":{"id":2,"label":"Service des ressources humaines","code":"RH"},"enabled":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"label":"Sonia Touahri","abregate":"ST"},
```

So as you can understand I want to keep in `DepartmentTmp` only the users which the departement match with the departement chosen in the filter.

Thanks,

Nicolas Guerin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a specific ng-model variable name and set the department id as value: eg: `ng-model="vm.choosenDepartment" ng-value="department.id"` 
so you could use a filter by department id like:

```
{department: {id: vm.choosenDepartment}}
```

With a normal html & ng-options:

```
<b>Choose pole:</b>
<select ng-model='vm.choosenDepartment' ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in vm.departmentList track by item.id">
</select>
<br/><b>result</b>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="i in  (vm.departmentTmp | filter:{department: {id: vm.choosenDepartment}})">{{i.label}}</li>
```

https://embed.plnkr.co/IELGfEvc0Q3h5a7x0MDl/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is working perfectly except in one case : I can't choose without filters one i have selected one.

When I use no filter, all the users should be displayed it works when I run for the first time the web but once i have selectioned a department filter i can't come back to 0.

Thanks Nicolas

Comment: @NicolasGuerin Just add an item with id=undefined in the departmentList  `{
    "id": undefined,
    "label": "All",
    "code": "All"
  }` here a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/IELGfEvc0Q3h5a7x0MDl?p=preview

Comment: I've created a button which delete vm.choosenDepartmen when I click on it (with a beautiful rubbishbin icon aha) Thanks for the help it's good now.